# Is there a way to timestamp a cell based on activity from another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating a scorecard for my team. I have instructed the users to insert their names by using a drop down which includes their name or typing their name in column G when they review an item.

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rng1 As Range
 Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("G:G"), Target)
 If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now() & " - " & Environ("username")
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 If Intersect(Range("G:G"), Target) = "" Then rng1.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
 End Sub
```

At the moment:
The sheet timestamps on the same row in column H all single actions in column G (this includes deleting names and changing names). If the users auto-fill a Run-time error '13' will pop up.

What I would like to do:
- Timestamp in column H when the user fills out their name in column G
- If the user auto-fills then a timestamp would be generated in the same row in column H also
- If cells in column G were cleared, the timestamp would clear also.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by auto-filling, but if more than cell is changed you can loop through 'Target' to avoid an error.

Then just check if the changed cell is empty, if so, clear H.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng1 As Range, r As Range

Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("G:G"), Target)

If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each r In rng1
    If r.Value = vbNullString Then
        r.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    Else
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now() & " - " & Environ("username")
    End If
    'for fans of brevity, replace the If clause with below
    'r.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(r.Value = vbNullString, vbNullString, Now() & " - " & Environ("username"))
Next r

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for explanation: Your type mismatch (runtime error 13) will be generated, when you are assigning a string (your timestamp) to a range that consists of more then one cell, or when you ask excel to compare a multicell range to a string (in your case " "). When a user autofills, then more than one cell is selected and you run into your error. With the given code of SJR, you are save.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This makes perfect sense.